# Setcookie PHP issue localhost vs normal domain

Tags: php, cookies, parameters, localhost, setcookie

I was working on my website on localhost (where it worked correctly) and then I moved it to classic domain, but there is issue with PHP setcookie function.

Here is my setcookie sample, basically it will take data from URL paramater called "ID" and then save it as cookie and then it will redirect to website to hide URL paramater.

Yes it works on localhost, but on normal website no..I dont know what to do please help me :)

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
$hafcookie = $_GET['id'];
setcookie( 'lolcookies', $hafcookie, time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60), COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN );
header( "refresh:0; url=http://mywebsite.com" ); 
}
```

Comment: is the `COOKIE_DOMAIN` value correctly placed as your domain?

Comment: how will I find out ? :)

Comment: I am using wordpress and in config.php I have 
`code`define( 'COOKIE_DOMAIN', 'mywebsite.com' );`code`

Comment: How do you know it is "not working" - what does the code look like where you check the value in the cookie?

Comment: I am checking it in browser settings if does that cookie exists and also I am checking through php $_COOKIE[$cookie_name] 
well it is weird that on localhost it is working, but on domain not

Comment: I figured that cookies are working correctly, but somehow url paramater is not recognized :/